# Java Swing border with no thickness

Tags: java, swing, border

I have a bunch of `JLabels` in a `GridBagLayout`. I would like to highlight which one is "selected" by adding a line border around the "selected one". The problem with this is that the thickness of the border separates the `JLabels` apart and forms gaps in between them all. Is it possible to make the border with 0 thickness but still be visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to make the border with 0 thickness but still be visible?

You can use a `CompoundBorder`. Create a `LineBorder` as the outer and an `EmptyBorder` (with -1 offsets) as the inner.

The total size of the Border will be 0 and not take up any space, but it will paint on top of the label, instead of outside the bounds of the label.

Comment: How do I do the offset?

Comment: @chris13524, you use `-1`, instead of `1` when you create the `EmptyBorder`.

Comment: That's an interesting hack, might need to remember that

Comment: Oh, got it. This is what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

Instead, set each "non-selected" `JLabel` with an `EmptyBorder` of the same pixel thickness as the `LineBorder`.

When selected, change the `Border` to a `LineBorder` and when unselected, change it to an `EmptyBorder`.

This will stop the layout from changing size...as it hasn't.

Also, a `Border` of `0` pixel thickness is...invisible...

Comment: Thanks! I thought the border with 0 thickness was invisible, but well, I don't know. Thanks again!

Comment: And also, EmptyBorder does not eccept thickness parms. Just going to use a LineBorder with my background color.

Comment: @chris13524 [`EmptyBorder(int, int, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html#EmptyBorder%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) would beg to differ